# Separate the config API with dev and prod webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Please tell me, here is the config.js file in it, the exported variable with a reference to the API, but there is an API for the dev version, and there is a separate API for the prod version, as I understand it, you need to make 2 separate files, but how to make it in webpack so that when dev he used one file, and prod another?

Below added webpack configuration files, a project on react.js (if that makes any difference :) )

rules.js

```js
const rules = [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ['babel-loader'],
  },
  {
    test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          mimetype: 'application/font-woff',
          name: '[name].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.[ot]tf(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
          name: '[name].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          mimetype: 'image/svg+xml',
          name: '[name].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico)$/i,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];

export default rules;
```

webpack.config.common.babel.js

```js
import path from 'path';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import Dotenv from 'dotenv-webpack';
import rules from './utils/rules';

const config = (env) => {
  const PUBLIC_PATH = env.production ? '/' : '/';

  return {
    entry: {
      index: './src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
      publicPath: PUBLIC_PATH,
      path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'dist'),
      filename: env.production ? '[name].js' : '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom',
        app: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/app/'),
        store: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/store/'),
        ui: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/ui/')
      },
      extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json', 'scss']
    },
    module: {
      rules
    },
    node: {
      dgram: 'empty',
      fs: 'empty',
      net: 'empty',
      tls: 'empty',
      child_process: 'empty'
    },
    plugins: [
      new Dotenv({
        systemvars: true
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'public/index.html',
        favicon: 'public/favicon.ico',
        inject: true,
        minify: {
          removeComments: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeRedundantAttributes: true,
          useShortDoctype: true,
          removeEmptyAttributes: true,
          removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
          keepClosingSlash: true,
          minifyJS: true,
          minifyCSS: true,
          minifyURLs: true
        }
      })
    ]
  };
};

export default config;
```

webpack.config.dev.babel.js

```js
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
import merge from 'webpack-merge';
import { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } from 'webpack-bundle-analyzer';
import common from './webpack.config.common.babel';

const config = env => merge(common(env), {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  target: 'web',
  mode: 'development',
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: '../dist',
    port: 3009,
    hot: true,
    clientLogLevel: 'none'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /(\.css|\.scss|\.sass)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
            options: { singleton: true }
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              /* eslint-disable global-require */
              plugins: () => [require('autoprefixer')],
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'scss')]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
});

export default config;
```

webpack.config.common.babel.js

```js
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import merge from 'webpack-merge';
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from 'mini-css-extract-plugin';
import common from './webpack.config.common.babel';

const config = env => merge(common(env), {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  target: 'web',
  mode: 'production',
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    nodeEnv: 'production',
    sideEffects: true,
    concatenateModules: true,
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /(\.css|\.scss|\.sass)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              /* eslint-disable global-require */
              plugins: () => [require('cssnano'), require('autoprefixer')],
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'scss')],
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].[chunkhash].css',
    })
  ],
});

export default config;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define two different npm scripts and use the `--config` flag for custom files (/file-paths):

```
"build:dev": "webpack --config ./webpack.client.dev.js",
"build:prod": "webpack --config ./webpack.client.prod.js"
```

For the common you have to use `webpack-merge`, for example:

const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'production',
    ... 
});
```

Comment: Well, I have 2 different versions of the script for the webpark for the prod and for the dev and also there is one common file, showed these files above, and how to make them use one apiconfig.js for the prod and the apiconfig.js on the dev?

Comment: You can define common as in my update. If you have two different settings for prod and dev, you need to use two files logically.